# How to use a web-embedded model in a computational workflow?

Tags: algorithms, monte-carlo

There is a model embedded in a web browser [(Caprio 1998)](http://web.archive.org/web/20011118202519/http://www.msstate.edu/Entomology/PGjava/ILSImodel.html) that I would like to use in an MCMC algorithm. What is the best way to do this?

I could implement the model in my favorite language but I would like to know if it is possible to either write a web-scraping / mechanize script to evaluates the model and dumps the output into a file, or somehow capture the existing model implementation as a desktop executable.

The interface is fairly straightforward:[image]

And I envision a script that takes the parameters in the fields on the left side as inputs, and returns the results provided in the right column of fields as outputs:

```
 ./runmodel.sh 0.001 0.002 1 0.04 0.001 1.0 1.0 0.5 0 > model.out
```

Can I efficiently do this using the current implementation (in Java 1.0), or should I just start from scratch?

Caprio, MA (1998) The evolution of resistance: a simple deterministic model. http://web.archive.org/web/20011118202519/http://www.msstate.edu/Entomology/PGjava/ILSImodel.html

Comment: Having the source code here http://web.archive.org/web/20020129140946/http://www.msstate.edu/Entomology/PGjava/NonRandomMatingModel/, wouldn't it be easier to write a simpler interface (say, getting rid of the GUI) in Java?

Comment: @Juanlu001 yep. That helps me for this specific case (but the question would still hold for the general case). I did not see that the code was available on my first pass. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Extracting data from a Java applet on the web seems complicated (see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948814/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-java-applet-inside-the-browser) and [this forum post](http://objectmix.com/jdbc-java/41680-extract-data-java-applet.html)), but if, for example, the data was available as ordinary web forms or, in general, in a more accesible way, there are some solutions in Python for web scraping:

- [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)
- [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to grab de data + [lxml](http://lxml.de/) / [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse it  (the latter option depending on its well-formedness)